# Filtered items not rendering when onClick is pushed (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to filter list of options when a certain criteria is met. The item that I wants shows up when I console.log but it doesn't render to the page. I have created a new state to hold the filtered items so that I won't mutate [listOfOptions], however when I do that it doesn't render. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong. I am using the Context API to traverse between states and I am new to React so I might be messing things up a bit. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
const getTotal = () => {
        const newProfitArr = []
        for (let i = 0; i < listOfOptions.length; i++) {
            newProfitArr.push(listOfOptions[i].totalProfit)
        }

        return newProfitArr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
            if (isNaN(accumulator) || isNaN(currentValue)) {
                return accumulator;
            }
            else return accumulator + currentValue
        }, 0);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        setTotalReturn(getTotal())

    })

   //This is where I am filtering the list of options array with the new function
    const gainOptionsTab = () => setNewTable(listOfOptions.filter(function (option) {
        return option.totalProfit > 0;
    }).map(function (option) {
        return option
    }))


    // const lossOptionsTab = () => setNewTable(listOfOptions.filter(function (option) {
    //     return option.totalProfit < 0;
    // }).map(function (option) {
    //     return option
    // }))


    //change active class
    function addTabBackground() {
        const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab]');
        window.onload = function () {
            tabs.forEach(tab => {
                tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    tabs.forEach(tab => {
                        tab.classList.remove('active')
                    })
                    tab.classList.add('active')
                })
            })
        }

    }

    addTabBackground()

    return (

        <nav className="navbar">
            <h1 id="gains">stock<span>ER</span></h1>
            <h2 style={{ color: totalReturn >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}>${totalReturn.toFixed(2)}</h2>
            <ul>
                <li data-tab="all" className="active">All</li>
                <li onClick={gainOptionsTab} data-tab="gains">Gains</li>
                <li data-tab="losses" id="lost" className="losses">Losses</li>
            </ul>
        </nav >

    )
}

 //Trying to filter this 
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.target.reset();
        addListOfOptions(
            {
                clock,
                name,
                price,
                amountOfOptions,
                totalAmountSpent,
                amountOfOptionsSold,
                optionPriceSoldAt,
                totalProfit

            }
        )
    }

    const getInputValue = (hookSetter) => (e) => {
        let { value } = e.target;
        return hookSetter(value)
    }

    const addListOfOptions = (lists) => {
        setListOfOptions([...listOfOptions, lists])
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        let getOptions = localStorage.getItem('options');
        if (getOptions) {
            setListOfOptions(JSON.parse(getOptions))
        } else return null
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('options', JSON.stringify(listOfOptions))

    }, [listOfOptions])

    useEffect(() => {
        setTotalAmountSpent((price * amountOfOptions) * 100)
        setTotalProfit((optionPriceSoldAt - price) * (amountOfOptionsSold * 100))
    })

    // const deleteItem = () => {
    //     listOfOptions.filter
    // }

    return (
        <div className="formoutputs">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" className="input stockname" placeholder="Enter Stock Symbol" onChange={getInputValue(setName)} />
                <input type="text" className="input stockprice" placeholder="Enter Option Price" onChange={getInputValue(setPrice)} />
                <input type="text" className="input stockamount" placeholder="Enter Number Of Option" onChange={getInputValue(setAmountOfOptions)} />
                <input type="text" className="input stockpricesold" placeholder="Enter Option Price Sold" onChange={getInputValue(setOptionPriceSoldAt)} />
                <input type="text" className="input stockamountsold" placeholder="Enter Number Of Option Sold" onChange={getInputValue(setAmountOfOptionsSold)} />
                <button type="submit" className="btn">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <div className="outputs" >
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Stock Name</th>
                            <th>Price Of Option</th>
                            <th>Number Of Options</th>
                            <th>Total Amount Spent</th>
                            <th>Option Sold At</th>
                            <th>Amount Of Options Sold</th>
                            <th>Proft</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    {listOfOptions.map(option => {

                        return (
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{option.clock}</td>
                                    <td>{option.name.toUpperCase()}</td>
                                    <td>${option.price}</td>
                                    <td>{option.amountOfOptions}</td>
                                    <td>${option.totalAmountSpent.toFixed(2)}</td>
                                    <td>${option.optionPriceSoldAt}</td>
                                    <td>{option.amountOfOptionsSold}</td>
                                    <td style={{ color: option.totalProfit >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}>${option.totalProfit.toFixed(2)}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        )
                    })}
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the code a bit? For example where does the first `useEffect` belong to? In your code it is not part of any component. Same for `handleSubmit` and so on.

Comment: @Raphael Those where the useState functions that I put in. I didn't think they were needed for the code. Do you want me to put those in?